# JQuery Delegate IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a pop-up menu that gets hidden when someone clicks elsewhere on the page.

```
$(window).delegate("body", 'click', hide);
```

This works everywhere except IE8. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: 1.6.4. I've tried to upgrade, but it breaks other parts of my page

Comment: Mmh have you tried Migrate? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Comment: #amazing This will help so much!

Comment: :-) happy to hear it! have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need `delegate` in this case?

```
$("body").on("click", hide);
```

For what it's worth, I think the original code is failing because in IE8 events do not bubble all the way up to the `window` object.   `$(window.document).delegate("body", "click", hide)` might work if you really want to use `delegate`.

Comment: Delegate hasn't actually been removed, only deprecated so it should still work...

Comment: Or you could use the delegation method with on()

Comment: @Zenith: I'm just questioning the need for registering a delegated event handler instead of just putting a click handler on the `body` element.  The use case in the OP is not really using delegated events.

Comment: How about just `$("body").click(hide);`? ^_^

Comment: @RocketHazmat - that should work too.  Out of habit I tend not to to use the shortcut methods like `click`, mostly because I am often binding to custom events that do not have shortcut methods.

Comment: @Brandon Mm I agree with your point about delegation, does seem unnecessary in this case. Interesting point about the propagation in IE8! Do you have any links in regard to that?

Comment: @Zenith: I do not have anything to read.  I just inferred it from the OP's problem.  Here is a jsFiddle, but jsFiddle does not seem to work in IE8 anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/guf3V/  But if you make a local htm file with this script and html, then the alert will not fire in IE8, though it does fire in Chrome.

Comment: I agree with @RocketHazmat, just use `click()`, there doesn't seem to be reason to delegates because there is only one `body` in the document.

Comment: Yea. I used click. Thanks. Brain fart on that one. I was trying to modify a plugin written for JQ 1.7